# JQuery search doesn't find all record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I created a page where you can search into a database (PHP, MySQL, JQuery).
It works fine, but I have a problem that I really don't understand.
If I search "abbandonato" it works accurately, but if I search "abband", "abbando", "abbandon", "abbandona" (and other parts of the string) it doesn't works. The returned error (text in alert) is "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". Why? If the query find "abbandonato", the query must find also a part of the string ("abbando", "abbandon",...).
With other words I don't have this problem.

Here is the code:

data2.php

```
$(function() {
                // Funzione per l'autocomplete
                $("#formSearch").submit(function(e) {
                    //Annulla default form action
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var ricerca= $("#tbSearch").val();

                    // Se il campo ricerca non è vuoto carico i dati
                    if ($("#tbSearch").val().length > 0) {
                        $('#searchResults').html("Caricamento...");
                        $.ajax({                                      
                            url: 'data3.php',                  
                            method: 'POST',
                            asynch: false,
                            data: {
                                dati: 1,
                                ricerca:ricerca
                            },        // Argomenti mandati in POST

                            dataType: 'json',                  
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#searchResults').html("Caricamento...");

                                var stringa = "";
                                for(var i in data) {
                                    stringa += '<tr><td>' + data[i]['disc'] + '</td>';
                                    stringa += '<td>' + data[i]['frm'] + '</td>';
                                    stringa += '<td>' + data[i]['lex'] + '</td></tr>';
                                }

                                $('#searchResults').html(stringa);
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(error);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

data3.php

```
<?php   
require('inc/db_connection.php');


$dati = $_POST["dati"];

if($dati == 1) {

    // Query    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT tab1.disc, tab1.frm, tab2.lex lex
                           FROM tab1, tab2 
                           WHERE tab1.disc = tab2.disc
                           AND BINARY LOWER(frm) LIKE BINARY LOWER('" . trim($_POST["ricerca"]) . "%')
                           LIMIT 0,500");
    // Array per AJAX
    $array_risultati = array();

    if (mysql_error())
        echo json_encode(array(mysql_error()));
    else {
        // Popolazione $array_risultati
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $array_risultati[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($array_risultati);
    }
}
```

Comment: may be the function is not sending JSON. remove `dataType: 'json'` from jQuery and print the data coming from the server.

Comment: Its `async: false,` not `asynch: false,`.

Comment: @php-sheep the JSON is empty, but I don't understand why! If I put the query in PHPMyAdmin it works fine.

Comment: @RohanKumar: thank you, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: remove `dataType: 'json'` and add `console.log(data);` just after `success: function(data) {` and tell me the output or add following lines into your php code `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @php-sheep With console.log(data) I get this Warning: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." I get the same message if I search "abbandonato", but under it there is the array with all results.
PHP results: ini_set('display_startup_errors',1) returns 1, ini_set('display_errors',1) returns 1, error_reporting(-1) returns 22519

Comment: @user2270069 It was a just to suggest not the solution.

Comment: thats because you are using sync requests. set `async: true` for a while also.

Comment: @php-sheep Ok. I suspect that the problem could be XAMPP... it could be possible? However if I set async "true" I don't get any message in console.

Comment: It was XAMPP! I uploaded page and DB on a server and it works fine. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`...LOWER(frm) LIKE BINARY CONCAT(LOWER('" . trim($_POST["ricerca"]), '%') . "')...`

I think what's happening is that `LOWER()` is converting the `'%'` as well and maybe causing problems. Move the `'%'` out of the `LOWER()` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing JSON headers in the PHP code.
Add following code before `json_encode`

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `BINARY` from your query and try like,

```
mysql_query("SELECT tab1.disc, tab1.frm, tab2.lex lex
                FROM tab1, tab2 
                WHERE tab1.disc = tab2.disc
                AND LOWER(frm) LIKE LOWER('".trim($_POST["ricerca"])."%')
            LIMIT 0,500");
```

May be `BINARY` converts the `%` to some other code which is appended to your search value and make some different word which is not found in your database.

For your reference read [Lesser Known MySQL Performance Tips](http://footle.org/2007/11/28/lesser-known-mysql-performance-tips/)

> if you need to do case-sensitive matching, declare your column as
>   BINARY; don't use LIKE BINARY in your queries to cast a non-binary
>   column. If you do, MySQL won't use any indexes on that column.